# Cannot export packages in systemverilog

Tags: package, system-verilog

I've tried to make a big package that exports sub packages for not to make any dependency in test files when new sub package is added. For this, I just simply did as in following but got a compile error, it seems export does not work properly as described in LRM. Is there any missing points in my code?

```
package sub_pkg_A;
  ..
endpackage

package sub_pkg_B;
  ..
endpackage

// just import and export
package top_pkg;
   import sub_pkg_A::*;
   import sub_pkg_B::*;
   export sub_pkg_A::*;
   export sub_pkg_B::*;
endpackage

// test file
module my_test;
    import top_pkg::*;
    ..
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the wildcard import statement `import pkg::*;` doesn't import any identifiers until there is an explicit reference to that identifier.

```
package sub_pkg_A;
  int A,B,C;
endpackage

// just import and export
package top_pkg;
   import sub_pkg_A::*; // A, B, C become candidates for importing
   int D = A; // imports A
   export sub_pkg_A::*; // exports A
   export sub_pkg_A::B; // imports/ exports B

endpackage

// test file
module my_test;
    import top_pkg::*; // A, B, D become candidates for importing. 
    ..
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, I just realized the meaning of wildcard. Is there any way that I can implicity import all definitions in the package. In some cases, It might take huge effort to import explicitly for the sub-packages that contain may stuffs (e.g. parameter, class, typedef)